# Tabs and webView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, tabview

It will become clear as you read that I have very little experience programming please excuse me for an elementary question. I have on the storyboard the template for a tab based app. which has two view controllers both of which have a web view on them and both seem to be working fine. As I needed a third tab I dragged a view controller onto the storyboard and linked it to the tab bar controller, I also created a "thirdViewContoller.swift" file which was copied from one of the other two which was in the template. Ran the app and everything works fine. I now drag a UiWebView onto the third view controller and unlike the other two when I try to control drag the webView to the code it will not link up. What am I missing. Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check that your `thirdViewController` class is set in the `storyboard`? Click the yellow circle on your third view controller that you added in the `storyboard`. Go to the **Identity inspector** tab. Make sure the "**Custom class:**" field is set to `thirdViewController`. Now you should be able to make an `IBOutlet` for your web view by control dragging.

Comment: @ ad121 thank you so very much ......only one thing it is in the identity inspector where you have to change it to the third view controller.  Many thanks

Comment: It would seem I don't have enough to up vote but if I did I would give lots of up votes to  @ad121

Comment: @Tom Yup that is my bad. I even checked XCode for the name before writing the answer but still wrote the wrong name :/. I'll edit my answer to the correct name.

Comment: @ad121no big deal you helped me fix a problem I had had for about a week, learning process :-) Many thanks again.